# How to replace avcodec_encode_audio2()/avcodec_encode_video2() with avcodec_send_frame() and avcodec_receive_packet()?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, libavcodec, muxer, avcodec

In muxing example in [link](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.4/muxing_8c_source.html) am attempting to use `avcodec_send_frame()` and `avcodec_receive_packet()` instead of `avcodec_encode_audio2()`/`avcodec_encode_video2()` as they are deprecated. In

```
  352     ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
  353     if (ret < 0) {
  354         fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding audio frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
  355         exit(1);
  356     }
  357 
  358     if (got_packet) {
  359         ret = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->st, &pkt);
  360         if (ret < 0) {
  361             fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing audio frame: %s\n",
  362                     av_err2str(ret));
  363             exit(1);
  364         }
  365     }
  366 
  367     return (frame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
```

and in

```
  522     ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_packet);
  523     if (ret < 0) {
  524         fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
  525         exit(1);
  526     }
  527 
  528     if (got_packet) {
  529         ret = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->st, &pkt);
  530     } else {
  531         ret = 0;
  532     }
  533 
  534     if (ret < 0) {
  535         fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
  536         exit(1);
  537     }
  538 
  539     return (frame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
```

What to assign `got_packet` variable with when using `avcodec_send_frame()` and `avcodec_receive_packet()` functions and how to change the code if I do?. I have tried this so far

```
ret = avcodec_send_frame(c, frame);
if (ret < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending the frame to the audio encoder\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (ret = 0) {
    got_packet = avcodec_receive_packet(c, &pkt);
    if (got_packet == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || got_packet == AVERROR_EOF){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving packet\n");
        return -1;}
    else if (got_packet < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding audio frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ret1 = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->st, &pkt);
    if (ret1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing audio frame: %s\n",
                av_err2str(ret1));
        exit(1);
    }
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
}
return (frame || got_packet) ? 0 : 1;
```

but isn't working and am having hard time getting it to work.

Comment: With a quick look, I couldn't spot what's wrong.
If you put your project somewhere (like github) for linux with makefile + the sample audio file. I can check it to see whats wrong.

Comment: @thekamilz I have provided the link to muxing.c in the question. Sample audio is not needed. The functions get_audio_frame(), open_audio() generates dummy audio frames and fill_yuv_image() generates dummy video frames. Am running it on ubuntu with command `gcc muxing.c -o muxing -lm -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lz -lswresample`

Comment: Ok, I see. It looks like `muxing.c` example uses old api. Perhaps you should check `encode_audio.c` and `encode_video.c` in this link: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/examples.html which uses new API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `avcodec_encode_video2()`, `got_packet_ptr` will be `0` when output packet is empty. The `got_packet_ptr` will equal `1` when output packet is non-empty and during draining mode (at end-of-file situations) when `NULL` is sent to `avcodec_encode_video2()` until all buffered items are flushed after which it becomes `0` again.

In new API, return value from `avcodec_receive_packet()` will be equal to `0` when buffer is full or when draining mode is entered, which is similar to `got_packet_ptr` being equal to `1`. The `avcodec_receive_packet()` otherwise returns negative error code `AVERROR(EAGAIN)` which means output is not available in the current state - user must try to send input or `AVERROR_EOF` i.e, the encoder has been fully flushed, and there will be no more output packets.

Using the new API in `muxing.c` example in the following way worked for me:

```
ret = avcodec_send_frame(c, frame);
if (ret < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame for encoding\n");
    exit(1);
}
while (ret >= 0) {
    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(c, &pkt);
    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF){
        return (ret==AVERROR(EAGAIN)) ? 0:1;
     }
    else if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    ret = write_frame(oc, &c->time_base, ost->st, &pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
       exit(1);
    }
    av_packet_unref(&pkt);
}
return (frame) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, why do we sit in a while loop ```while(ret >=0)``` and not in an ```if``` condition :) ?

Comment: A side-by-side example of replacement can be found here: https://github.com/ferdymercury/amide/pull/23/files

Comment: Also useful: https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01000-97990449-e9f9-4b26-839a-b8c4cad60efa